# How to pass the value using ajax to the controller in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Here is my ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){
              var value_to_send = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
                  //alert(this.value);
                      return this.value;
              }).get().join(', ');

          });
        });
```

Here,its my URL '/hotel/hotelresults/'.folder_name/function_name and the my Controller Name is HotelController

How should I get the ""return this.value"" using ajax to the controller.
Can Someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much @rome 웃
I Tried like this..

```
$(document).ready(function()
            {
              $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){ 
                  console.log($('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
                      // alert(this.value);
                      var value = this.value;
                      $.ajax({
                        // alert();
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "hotelresults",
                        data: {
                            key : value
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            // alert(data);
                        }
                    });

                  }).get().join(', '));

              });
            });
```

And in Route:

```
Route::get('hotel/hotelresults', 'HotelController@postHotelresults');
```

And in my Controller:

```
public function postHotelresults(Request $request)
    {
        //
       return $request->key; //or return Input::get('key');
    }
```

Because of giving the URL as  "url: "hotel/hotelresults"," It seems to be an error in my console

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "hotel/hotelresults",
                    data: {
                        key : value
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data)
                    }
                });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('hotel/hotelresults', 'YourController@YourMethod');
```

In YourController:

```
public function YourMethod(Request $request)
    {
        //
       return $request->key; //or return Input::get('key');
    }
```

Please read more
 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers)

Comment: How should I access this value in my controller ??  using $ symbol !!!... @rome 웃

Comment: And another thing is where should I write this ajax in my script..I gave it inside the "$('.i-check:checked').map(function() {});" function but it don't work..It even din't show the alert... @rome

Comment: I din't get anything.It shows only the empty page..when I gave the "return $request->key; " in my controller

Comment: Did you use `alert(data)`? `ajax` not return a page.

Comment: Yep I use it..And I check it by using alert(); inside the $ajax{( )}; whether it get into the ajax or not..But it din't show any alert..